# Ability to customize the icons in matstepper in angular material2

Tags: angular, angular-material

Currently users are locked into using the Material `create` and `done` icon for the step headers. These changes add the ability to customize the icons by providing an `ng-template` with an override.
So I have found the [update](https://github.com/crisbeto/material2/commit/f120014de59bcfdeeb7316ff0c302a107b4276da) 
but when I use it as

```
<mat-horizontal-stepper [linear]="isLinear">
  <mat-step [stepControl]="firstFormGroup">
    <form [formGroup]="firstFormGroup">
      <ng-template matStepLabel>Fill out your name</ng-template>
      <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
        <custom-icon>edit</custom-icon>
       </ng-template>
      <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput placeholder="Last name, First name" formControlName="firstCtrl" required>
      </mat-form-field>
      <div>
        <button mat-button matStepperNext>Next</button>
      </div>
    </form>
  </mat-step>
  <mat-step>
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
    You are now done.
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
    </div>
  </mat-step>
</mat-horizontal-stepper>
```

I get this error

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
    'custom-icon' is not a known element:
    1. If 'custom-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
    2. If 'custom-icon' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

How can I give my desired icons

Comment: Hi @Aranganathan there is an update for customizing icon, it might help you and please let me also know

Comment: Hi @Unnikrishnan M R could you please give any leads as to how can i change the icons and background color of mat stepper header

Answer (score 8):

Just [install material icons](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-6-optional-add-material-icons)

if already installed, add import in your module

```
import {MatIconModule} from '@angular/material/icon';
@NgModule({
   imports: [
     MatIconModule
]
})
```

if already imported, use instead of `<custom-icon>` `<mat-icon>`

```
<mat-vertical-stepper>
    <ng-template matStepperIcon="edit">
            <mat-icon>check</mat-icon>
    </ng-template>
   <!-- Stepper steps go here -->
   <mat-step label="step 1">step 1 content</mat-step>
   <mat-step label="step 2">step 2 content</mat-step>
   <mat-step label="step 3">step 3 content</mat-step>
</mat-vertical-stepper>
```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5fcrjd)

Comment: Right now the official documentation uses <custom-icon> that doesn't work instead of a <mat-icon> that actually works! thanks